# Matplotlib: simpler code for common plot setting, such as legend, lable, title, figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

As I use matplotlib more and more, I find setting the figure cumbersome, for example

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,2,6,7,2]
plot(x, y, '-', label='test')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('This is my title')
ax.set_xlabel('X name')
ax.set_ylabel('Y name')
ax.legend()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(4,4)
```

[image]

For I make a sufficient plot, **too many lines are simply about the figure configuration**.

I want to know, if there are simple ways to do this? For example, in `pandas` we can do

```
df['my_column'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,4), ....)
```

---

Currently, I solve this problem by define a `plt_configure()` function,

[image]

The code looks like

```
def plt_configure(ax=None, xlabel=None, ylabel=None, title='', legend=False, tight=False, figsize=False, no_axis=False):
    if ax == None :
        ax=plt.gca()
        plt.suptitle(title)
    else:
        ax.set_title(title)

    if xlabel:
        ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    if ylabel:
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend:
        if isinstance(legend, dict):
            ax.legend(**legend)
        else:
            ax.legend()
    if tight:
        if tight == 'xtight' or tight == 'x':
            ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
        elif tight == 'ytight':
            ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
        else:
            ax.axis('tight')
    if figsize:
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(figsize)
    if no_axis:
        plt.gca().axis('off')
        legend = ax.legend()
        if legend:
            legend.remove()
```